# Exporting Concept From Module

Tags: c++, module, c++20, c++-concepts

I can't find nothing about C++ modules and concepts interaction. Is the syntax of exporting concept from module correct?

```
export module Module;

template <typename S>
export concept sequence = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

`export` exports *declarations*. A concept definition is a declaration and can therefore be exported. It works just like exporting any other declaration, as far as the results of such an export work.

As for the specific grammar, `export` is applied to the "declaration" grammar rule. And "template-declaration" is a kind of "declaration". A "template-declaration" includes the template header, but the grammatical definition for "template-declaration" says that [it's a "template-head" followed by a "declaration"](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.pre#1) *or* a "template-head" followed by a "concept-definition".

So just from the grammar, if you want to `export` a concept definition, you have to do it before the template header, since `concept-definition` doesn't include `export` as valid grammar.

However, if you're wondering about exporting regular templates, one might think that, from this grammar, `export` could come before the "template-head" or after. *However*, the [standard specifically says this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.pre#4):

> [A template-declaration's] *declaration* shall not be an *export-declaration*.

From this, we conclude that *all templates* put `export` before the template-head.

Comment: I think showing an example with valid syntax would be helpful.

Comment: @SergeKork: "*So, your answer is:*" ... I don't know what you're trying to say here. The answer seems pretty clear to me. You can look at either the third paragraph or the last paragraph.

Comment: So, your answer is: 

export module Module; 
export template <typename S> concept sequence = true; 

(Formatting problems, sorry)